# Запятая при деепричастном обороте (теснота связи)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Все мы знаем, что есть правило, гласящее, что не выде­ля­ет­ся запя­той дее­при­ча­стие, тес­но свя­зан­ное по смыс­лу со сказуемым.

Вопрос: как понять, тесно связаны они по смыслу или нет? И чем эта теснота связи определяется? Является ли это факультативным?

Пример:

*Дедушка ясно, сознательно улыбнулся, показав дёсны, и проговорил что-то тихо.*
Почему здесь нет тесной связи?

*Она сидела наклонив голову.*
Почему тут есть тесная связь?

Comment: Примеры Розенталя

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Многие считают, что тесная связь определяется исключительно **семантикой**. Важно, мол, что она не просто сидела, а сидела в определенной позе.

Но это не  совсем так: в действительности тесная связь задается **структурой предложения** и расстановкой **логических ударений** в нем.

(1) *Она сидела **наклонив гОлову** и не слУшала его.*

*Он о чем-то спросил ее. Но она сидЕла, **наклонив гОлову**, и больше не вслушивалась в  его слова — все самое важное было уже сказано.*

Здесь первую часть второго предложения трудно прочитать в одну фразу, поэтому мы обособляем оборот. Обратим внимание, что при обособлении ударение падает **и на глагол, и на оборот.**

(2) *Дедушка ясно, сознательно улыбнУлся, **показав дЁсны**, и проговорил что-то тИхо.*

А вот для этого предложения трудно подобрать парный вариант без обособления. Скорее всего, из=за совершенного вида глагола и деепричастия. Легче обособляются короткие обороты, которые легче вписываются в структуру предложения.

А как же **семантика?** Разве не смысл — это самое главное? Но дело в том, что автор т**ак строит** предложение, чтобы нужный смысл прочитывался правильно.